# extract field from file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed, scripting, regular-expression

I have bash script to collect all hardware info but following memory info piece is missing, so this is what i am trying to do.

Following command give you status of `DIMM` memory module,

```
[root@Linux ~]# hpasmcli -s 'show dimm'

DIMM Configuration
------------------
Processor #:                     1
Module #:                     1
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1333 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       Ok

Processor #:                     1
Module #:                     12
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1333 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       Ok

Processor #:                     2
Module #:                     1
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1333 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       Ok

Processor #:                     2
Module #:                     12
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1333 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       DIMM is degraded
```

want to extract `Size:` and `Status:` and need that in single line, like following

Final output will look like following. I can use other language like python or perl but i wrote in bash so i need something in bash, i can do multiple `for loop` and play with variable to make it work but i need something easy or in-short single like like `sed/awk`. how can i achieve that in sed/awk?

```
8192MB - Ok
8192MB - OK
8192MB - OK 
8192MB - DIMM is degraded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that doesn't `grep | awk | sed | awk`, but rather just uses one `awk`:

```
hpasmcli -s 'show dimm' | awk 'BEGIN { stick=0 } $1 == "Size:" { dimm[++stick] = $2" "$3} $1 == "Status:" { $1=""; status[stick]=$0 }  END {for( i in dimm ) { print dimm[i], "-", status[i] } }'
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - DIMM is degraded
```

The `awk` script, reformatted for readability:

```
BEGIN { 
  stick=0 
} 
$1 == "Size:" { 
  dimm[++stick] = $2" "$3
} 
$1 == "Status:" { 
  $1="" 
  status[stick]=$0
}  
END {
  for( i in dimm ) { 
    print dimm[i], "-", status[i] 
  } 
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy i think i did it :)

```
[root@Linux ~]# hpasmcli -s 'show dimm' | egrep -e Size -e Status | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' | awk 'NR%2{printf "%s - ",$0;next;}1'
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - Ok
8192 MB - DIMM is degraded
```

Still i would like to know if anyother way we can do that, i am not going to answer my question i will wait for other folks to chime in.